# From where CultureInfo.CurrentCulture reads culture

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I want to know the setting or location from where  `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` reads its value.

I am using a windows 7 laptop and have changed my system's regional and date-time settings to US.

I got my code working using below setting in web.config under

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) says

> The culture is a property of the executing thread. This read-only property is equivalent to retrieving the CultureInfo object returned by the Thread.CurrentCulture property. When a thread is started, its culture is initially determined by calling the Windows **GetUserDefaultLocaleName** function.

In other words, it's based on the Thread, witch has a context... in the ASP.NET context, that comes from the **Locale** used in the **client Browser first** if using `Server Variables` or the System Settings on everything else.

Under this Web context you can get it using the `Server.Variables` method on `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and you will get something like:

```
en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-PT;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
```

Witch states that the client browser has 3 languages set, where the first one is `en-US`.

Everything from `System.Globalization` comes from the **System definitions** just like the image below shows:

[image]

code above is:

```cs
<p>
    <pre>System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture</pre> 
    is @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName
</p>
```

No matter what browser is in use, the definition for `System.Globalization` will always come from the Operating System definition

[image]

Comment: Thanks Balexandre, this seems to be good info. But I just checked my browsers locale setting and its en-US(I am using firefox and I checked setting general.useragent.locale under about:config) also my systems datetime and regional settings were set to en-US. But still I get en-IN when checking System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. Do you have any idea where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5):

After spending 8 hours -- Find out a solution Thanks to Ronald -- [CultureInfo values differ between applications for the same culture. Is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322910/cultureinfo-values-differ-between-applications-for-the-same-culture-is-this-a-b/14323336#14323336)

> It turns out that regional settings are stored per user in Windows.
>   This is something I should have been aware of. Updating the
>   application pool to run as myself produced the same result across both
>   applications.
>
> To be fair, what is still confusing is how Network Service (the
>   account the application pool was running under) came to have the
>   incorrect value. I'm not even sure how I'd rectify that.
>
> Edit:
>
> If you need to update the regional settings for reserved accounts. You
>   have two options.
>
> ```
> Control Panel > Regional Settings > Click the administrative tab and then select "Copy Settings".
> ```
>
> On the screen that launches, ensure
>   you check "Welcome Screen and system accounts". Older versions of
>   Windows are similar I believe.
>       For the brace. Registry: HKEY_USERS > SID... > Control Panel > International. The security identifier for Network Service is: SID:
>   S-1-5-20.
>
> Ensure you restart the application pool for settings to take effect.

I did #1 -- and it did a trick for me!

Answer (score 2):

In case of ASP.NET, from

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Control Panel\International\`

S-1-5-20 is the security identifier of the Network Service "user" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330)

For other types of applications, refer to the documentation of GetUserDefaultLocaleName function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For an easy GUI way of changing the locale of S-1-5-20, see sitecorebasics's answer

Answer (score 1):

It uses the windows `GetUserDefaultLocaleName` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx