# Check if dateTime is a weekend or a weekday

Tags: c#, datetime

```
<script Language="c#" runat="server">
  void Page_Load()
  {
   DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
   dateToday.Text = " " + date.ToString("d");
   DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
   dayToday.Text = " " + day.ToString();

   if ((dayToday == DayOfWeek.Saturday) && (dayToday == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    {
    Console.WriteLine("This is a weekend");
    }

 }
</script>
```

Using dateTime, I am trying to test whether or not the current date is a weekday or weekend, then I would like to print the response to the user. Currently I am receiving a Runtime Error. If I remove my if statement the first items (the current date, and the day of the week) print properly.

Comment: It can't be saturday _AND_ sunday

Comment: Why call DateTime.Now twice? Under certain conditions the second call could be the next day and your `day` of week would not match your `date`.

Comment: @gknicker - That would be under very certain conditions. Like literal milliseconds of difference as barely anything happens between the firt DateTime.Now and the second one. That said - I do agree with you that date should be used in the second instance

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You wrote wrong varable in the following if statement:

```
if ((dayToday == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (dayToday == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a weekend");
}
```

instead of *dayToday* you must use *day* varable in the condition.

**UPDATE:**
Also you made mistake in condition. There must be `or` instead of `and`.

**Correct code is**

```
if ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a weekend");
}
```

Comment: This should be an OR condition. It can't be both Saturday AND Sunday.

Comment: @neonScarecrow, you are absolutely right. I did not pay attention this.

Comment: What about people in places like the middle east where the weekend is Friday/Saturday and not Saturday/Sunday?

Comment: @meh-uk, then you can create `List<DayOfWeek> weekends` for each culture and so your code will as follows: `if(weekends.Contains(dayToday)) ...`

Comment: `dayToday` is `TextBox ` type and it is asp control. You can't use `TextBox`type equal to `enum` type. You have to use `day` variable insted of  `dayToday` as `if (day==DayOfWeek.Saturday. || ...)`

Comment: Does this code work for any culture?

Answer (score 14):

You are comparing your ASP.NET label `dayToday` against an enumeration element of `DayOfWeek` which of course fails

Probably you want to replace `dayToday` with `day` in your `if` statement, i.e. from

```
if ((dayToday == DayOfWeek.Saturday) && (dayToday == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```

to

```
if ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) && (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```

---

In addition, you probably also want to replace the logical 'and' (`&&`) with a logical 'or' (`||`) to finally

```
if ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((day >= DayOfWeek.Monday) && (day<= DayOfWeek.Friday))
{
    // action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving an error because you are comparing an enum with a string.

```
// dayToday is a string
// DayOfWeek.Saturday is an enum
if ((dayToday == DayOfWeek.Saturday) && (dayToday == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
```

Use `DayOfWeek.Saturday.ToString()` to compare against a string. You will also want not to pad the `dayToday` string. Alternatively, use the `day` variable to compare against an enum.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUGJ0J

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        string dateToday = date.ToString("d");
        DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        string dayToday = day.ToString();

        // compare enums
        if ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateToday + " is a weekend");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateToday + " is not a weekend");
        }

        // compare strings
        if ((dayToday == DayOfWeek.Saturday.ToString()) || (dayToday == DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateToday + " is a weekend");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateToday + " is not a weekend");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand what I did wrong!

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<DateTime> datelist = new List<DateTime>();

        int balanceday = 1;
        while (datelist.Count < 10)
        {
            DateTime day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(balanceday + datelist.Count).Date;
            if (day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                datelist.Add(day);
            }
            else
            {
                balanceday++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if dateTime is a weekend or a weekday?

The answer for DateTime object is:

```
public bool IsWeekend(DateTime date)
{
    return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
    
[Fact]
public void IsWeekend()
{
    IsWeekend(new DateTime(2023, 09, 16)).ShouldBe(true);
    IsWeekend(new DateTime(2023, 09, 17)).ShouldBe(true);
    IsWeekend(new DateTime(2023, 09, 15)).ShouldBe(false);
}
```

Comment: "The remaining answers are server culture sensitive and are incorrect." What aspect of *every answer here* do you believe to be culture-sensitive?

Comment: Moreover *this* answer is very, very wrong - you're using `DateTime.Day`, which returns the day of the month. Your code will say it's the weekend on the 6th day of every month (in the Gregorian calendar), regardless of what month it is. `date.Day` will never be equal to `(int) DayOfWeek.Sunday`, which is zero...

Comment: Sorry I fix the code. I do not test it :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Because the default culture depends on the server installation and configuration. So you get form ToString() "Poniedziałek" in Polish.

Comment: Only if you call `DateTime.ToString()` - which *most* answers to this question don't, including the accepted answer. Providing an incorrect answer and claiming that all the other answers are wrong, despite most of them being correct, is really not great...

Comment: And in fact, using `ToString` on a DayOfWeek value is fine. Calling `date.ToString("D")` for the purposes of comparison is broken - but yours is the *only* answer that does that anywhere. Everything else that uses `date.ToString()` only uses it for display purposes, not for comparison.

Comment: @JonSkeet:  All 'dayToday' parameters use ToString() to get it in all answers and it is used to compare not to display.

Comment: The only answer which shows the initialization of `dayToday` (Shaun Luttin's) shows calling `ToString()` *on a DayOfWeek value*, i.e. the enum. Please give details as to where else you believe `ToString()` is being called *on a DateTime value* and the result being used for comparison. (Akshey Bhat's answer will fail as well, but not due to culture issues.)

Comment: Note that the property assignment in the question: `dayToday.Text = " " + day.ToString();` - does *not* call `ToString()` on a DateTime. `day` is already a `DayOfWeek`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The title of question is "Check if dateTime is a weekend or a weekday" not DayOfWeek. Anyway we can not use ToString() to check this.

Comment: No, it's not. The result of calling ToString on a DayOfWeek value does *not* depend on the culture.

Comment: (dateToday will depend on the culture, but dayToday won't.)

Comment: @JonSkeet 'dayToday 'is initialized in question, the answers use this initialization. 
Shaun Luttin's answer as you mentioned is also wrong. 
The second part of the answer works on strings and DayOfWeek not on DateTime. The first part of the answer works on DayOfWeek not on DateTime. Although you can somehow be satisfied with this first part of answer.

Comment: "The second part of the answer works on strings and DayOfWeek not on DateTime" - yes, but **that will work** - it's not culture-sensitive. (It's not a great idea to call ToString pointlessly, but it won't give the wrong answer.) If you're going to claim someone's answer is wrong, you should be ready to back it up: please provide a full example (e.g. as a gist) of where Shaun's answer gives the wrong result.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In general, you need to be careful when calling the ToString() method on an enum. This method may be overwritten. I don't see much point in comparing strings when you can compare enums (DayOfWeek). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833591/how-to-override-tostring-on-enum-in-c
Lets implement this as random value :)

Comment: No, you *can't* override `Enum.ToString()`. And I agree, there's not much point in comparing strings, but that doesn't mean that Shaun's answer is *wrong*. Your culture test, however, is *very* broken. 1) It implies that the culture used for parsing a DateTime is somehow persisted (it isn't) and 2) it uses "D" to format the date, supposedly to a string value of the day-of-week, which should be "dddd"; 3) it tests whether the string representation of a Saturday contains Sunday! A much better test would look like this: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/08f7993de8f6131c7048a611f8b62de8

Comment: @JonSkeet. Ok I can't override Enum.ToString().  Culture used for parsing a DateTime is somehow persisted on server level the windows OS can have installed only one specific culture witch is useed as invariant culture. https://serverfault.com/questions/980215/asp-net-core-site-has-the-wrong-default-culture-when-run-with-iis

Comment: "Culture used for parsing a DateTime is somehow persisted on server level" - no, it really, really isn't. This is an area where I'm reasonably expert (as the main author of Noda Time). The value of a `DateTime` absolutely does *not* know anything about how it was parsed, any more than an `int` knows whether it was parsed from a string as hex or decimal. If you believe it does, please provide a [mcve] in a new question and I'll explain whatever you're seeing.

Comment: @JonSkeet: So how generate DateTime.ToString("D") result without culture ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you don't supply a culture it uses the thread's current culture. That has nothing to do with the `DateTime` value you call it on. I suggest you ask a question in a new post if you want to know more though... and I'd suggest either editing your answer to remove the incorrect and misleading information, or delete it (given that the accepted answer already has the important part).

Comment: @JonSkeet. It is. How resolve parsing from string without culture? Logically it is impossible.

Comment: I do not want ask this. I know It. Its only logic current culture is defined on server level for example on pool aplication. But still pool apliaction mast know this culture from os registry.

Comment: "How resolve parsing from string without culture? Logically it is impossible." Sure, but I don't think I've ever said anything to contradict this. What I've said is that the culture used to parse the `DateTime` is not persisted as *part* of the `DateTime`... which means that if you parse from Polish, but then call `ToString()` without specifying a culture (as your test does) that will use the current thread culture, *not* Polish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255247/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-user1785960).

Comment: @JonSkeet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697604/from-where-cultureinfo-currentculture-reads-culture

Comment: That doesn't contradict anything I've said. Your test parses using Polish, with the clear implication that `date.ToString("D")` will *also* use Polish - it won't, unless that's the current thread culture. Your test should create the `DateTime` value using the normal year/month/day constructor (like your other test) and then pass the culture when calling `ToString`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok I deleted test it can be better I can achive the same by set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture before ToString, but it doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your asp controls inside form tag with runat="server".

```
<body>
    <form id="frm" runat="server">
    <p>
    Today's date is: <asp:Label ID="dateToday" runat="server" />
    <br/>
    The day of the week is: <asp:Label ID="dayToday" runat="server" />
    <br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Signature of `Page_Load` method is incorrect in your code. Also you should use `Response.Write` for asp websites instead of `Console.Writeline`. There should be OR(||) instead of AND(&&) when you are checking for the day of the week.

```
 <script language="c#" runat="server">
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                dateToday.Text = " " + date.ToString("d");
                DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
                dayToday.Text = " " + day.ToString();

                if ((dayToday.Text == DayOfWeek.Saturday.ToString()) || (dayToday.Text == DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString()))
                {
                    Response.Write("This is a weekend");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: The space here in `dayToday.Text = " " + day.ToString();` will prevent the comparison from being performed correctly - and it would be better to perform the comparison without using strings at all.