# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime - but it runs smoothly in another server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jqgrid

My current Win 2008 R2 server migrating to Azure. So that Im moving a web application to Azure Server Win 2008 R2.

Currently, I am facing the issue where it shows

> "Message":"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.","StackTrace":"   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)\r\n   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)\r\n   at... `

Purpose of the code: Its a JQGrid library, If the code runs successfully, I will proceed to update a table. This code runs when user clicks the update button and before updating the table as validation of date.

Weird question is: My On-Prem server runs this code smoothly, all data in Azure and On-Prem server are same.

**NEWLY ADDED:** When I edit some rows (so far only 1 row out of 100), it works.

Working row details: [image: Working row details]

Not working row details: [image: Not working row details]

JQuery code snippet:

```
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        url: '/SFI/WebService/StaffMaster.asmx/CheckEditStaff_AssignedRoster',
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        mtype: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        serializeEditData: function (postData) {
            var PrivilegeID = $('#hdnMAPrivilegeID').val();
            eStaffID = $("#StaffID").val();
            eStaffNo = $("#StaffNo").val(),
            eNewEndDate = $("#EffectiveEnd").val();
            eStaffName = $("#StaffName").val(),
            eIdentificationNo = $("#IdentificationNo").val(),
            eDOB = $("#DOB").val(),
            eEffectiveStart = $("#EffectiveStart").val(),
            eEffectiveEnd = $("#EffectiveEnd").val(),
            eGradeCode = $("#GradeDetails").val(),
            eStaffType = $("#StaffType").val(),
            eOrgUnit = $("#OrgUnit").val(),
            eEmail= $("#Email").val().toLowerCase()

            return JSON.stringify(
            {
                StaffID: $("#StaffID").val(),
                NewEndDate: $("#EffectiveEnd").val(),
                OldEndDate: StaffOldEndDte
            });
            .
            .
            .
            StaffOldEndDte = $("#EffectiveEnd").val();
```

Web Service Call in C#:

```
    public string CheckEditStaff_AssignedRoster(string StaffID,string NewEndDate,string OldEndDate)
    {
        string status = "0";
        bool Changed = false;
        DateTime dtnew;
        DateTime dtOld;

        dtnew = Convert.ToDateTime(NewEndDate);
        dtOld = Convert.ToDateTime(OldEndDate);


        if ((dtOld != dtnew)  && (dtnew < dtOld))
        {                
            Changed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = "1";
        }

        if (Changed)
        {                
            if (some condition...)
            {
                .
                .
                //do something...
            }
            else
            {
                status = "1";
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Comment: most probably the two servers have different culture, thus datetime format. If Azure is in US it will have MM-DD-YYYY and maybe your onpremise server has DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: @apomene. I have provided the screenshots of working rows and non-working

Comment: As per yellow highlighted rows, it is clear that you have culture issue. 31/12/9999 is a valid DT if date format is   DD/MM/YYYY where as if your format is MM/DD/YYYY it is invalid datetime

Comment: @MohammedShereif *don't* store dates as strings to begin with. If you *have* to, use the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. In JavaScript, use [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). This is a problem in the code, not .NET or Windows.

Comment: @MohammedShereif the de-facto standard for dates in JSON is the ISO8601 format anyway

Comment: @MohammedShereif what is `EffectiveEnd`? A text input? jQuery Date picker? Or an `input` with a `date` or `datetime` type? In all those cases you can get a `Date` object instead of a string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it a column which is in `formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y' }`

Comment: @MohammedShereif I asked about the HTML element, not the column. What is it? What you send to the server, any server should *NOT* use a localized format. The way to fix this is to read the date from the input element as an ISO 8601 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After knowing some knowledge on different cultures on DateTime format, from the question's comment, I moved to search again on how to make it the same as my on-premise server to new azure server (**Because I have already developed a working code in my on-premise server**). Found that, i can just change the 'Region and Language' setting same as on-premise to azure. Below is the link I used.

Here is the link: [From where CultureInfo.CurrentCulture reads culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697604/from-where-cultureinfo-currentculture-reads-culture)

Comment: That's not a fix, this covers up the problem. When you try to call another service you'll end up with the same problem - no service expectes localized dates, all expect dates in the ISO8601 format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, this is a lesson for me to use the standard formats in future developments. I posted this answer for those having the same as my situation. Because it took 2.5 days just for this fix.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment before, different cultures might be the problem. Using InvariantCulture in your code might help. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Here's the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs) of this method:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return new DateTime(0);
    return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

As you can see, it uses the current culture to parse the string.

What you should be using is [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) or at least [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) and give it the exact format and correct culture info you're attempting to parse to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your lines:

```
    dtnew = Convert.ToDateTime(NewEndDate);
    dtOld = Convert.ToDateTime(OldEndDate);
```

To

```
    dtnew = DateTime.ParseExact(NewEndDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //or however your JS is formatting the date as string
    dtOld = DateTime.ParseExact(OldEndDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //or however your JS is formatting the date as string
```

If you have a `Date` in JS and you use `toJSON` it should return a string in "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" - see [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) for more discussion